# modsecurity regex not always matching simple rule

Tags: regex, mod-security

Im trying to create a simple modsecurity regex rule that stops processing the rules when a match is found and just returns status 200 on a POST request so that it doesnt continue and get blocked by another CRS rule later in the chain.

Heres my rule:

```
    SecRule REQUEST_URI "@rx ^(?i)/cgi-bin/myPHPScript.php" \
                        "id:3021,allow,phase:2,nolog"
```

What happens is that sometimes the rule runs and is allowed, but other times modsecurity continues and gets caught by modsecurity's built in CRS rules after this rule and I cant seem to figure out why? I am new to modsecurity and have been reading all the online docs but have not found the answer yet.  I have also tried regex rules which (in other places Ive used regex) were used slightly differently with the same results.  Sometimes they work and other times they do not.

```
"@rx ^/\cgi-bin\/myPHPScript\.php"
"@rx ^.*\/cgi-bin\/myPHPScript\.php.*$"
```

I want to understand whats wrong with this particular situation because I have other
more complex regex scripts I want to allow as well so understanding the issue with this
one should apply to the others.

Thank you in advance.

[EDIT]

It appears that when:

```
SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly
```

one needs to set:

```
ctl:ruleEngine=Off
```

or

```
ctl:ruleEngine=On
```

when trying to use `allow` with `DetectionOnly`

According to this article:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58452059/modsecurity-is-turning-off-the-rule-engine-really-necessary-when-implementing-a

Example:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@rx ^(?i)/cgi-bin/myPHPScript.php" \
                        "id:3021,allow,phase:2,nolog,ctl:ruleEngine=On"
```